# Handling multiple ajax requests, only do the last request

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm doing a project that fetch different types of data from SWAPI API (people, planets, etc.) using react but I have an issue with multiple `Ajax` request.

The problem is when I quickly request from 2 different `URL` for example, 'species' and 'people', and my last request is 'species' but the load time of 'people' is longer, I will get 'people' instead.
What I want is to get the data of the last clicked request, if that make sense.

How do I achieve that? All the solution I found from Google is using jQuery.

Here's a slice of my code in `src/app.js` (root element) :

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
    searchfield: '',
    data: [],
    active: 'people'
 }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getData();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(this.state.active !== prevState.active) {
    this.getData();
  }
}

getData = async function() {
  console.log(this.state.active);
  this.setState({ data: [] });
  let resp = await fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/${this.state.active}/`);
  let data = await resp.json();
  let results = data.results;
  if(data.next !== null) {
    do {
      let nextResp = await fetch(data.next);
      data = await nextResp.json();
      let nextResults = data.results
      results.push(nextResults);
      results = results.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b) }, []);
    } while (data.next);
  }
  this.setState({ data: results});
}

categoryChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ active: e.target.getAttribute('data-category') });
}

render() {
  return (
    <Header searchChange={this.searchChange} categoryChange={this.categoryChange}/>
  );
}
```

I made a gif of the problem [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/423466902879338497/458456361068527617/problem.gif).
Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm writing this on my phone.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store your requests somewhere and to abandon old ones by making only one request active. Something like:

```
getData = async function() {
  console.log(this.state.active);
  this.setState({ data: [] });

  // my code starts here
  if (this.controller) { controller.abort() }
  this.controller = new AbortController();
  var signal = controller.signal;
  let resp = await fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/${this.state.active}/`, { signal });
  let data = await resp.json();
  let results = data.results;
  if(data.next !== null) {
    do {
      let nextResp = await fetch(data.next);
      data = await nextResp.json();
      let nextResults = data.results
      results.push(nextResults);
      results = results.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b) }, []);
    } while (data.next);
  }
  this.setState({ data: results});
}
```

Comment: when the code reaches the `if(this.controller)` I get `'controller' is not defined`, and also I had to use abortcontroller-polyfill to make it work because I used `create-react-app` (forgot to mention this) or else I'll get `'AbortController' is not defined`, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Re 1st: strange thing. Try to `this.controller = null`  in your component. Re 2: maybe, it looks like you're using **very** old browser

Comment: Using the 1st method I still get the `'controller' is not defined` error, my browser is at the latest version actually, I used abortcontroller-polyfill because of [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abortcontroller-polyfill#using-it-along-with-create-react-app). Maybe I should use different method to make request? idk

Comment: Please provide codesandbox. I can't understand without getting my hands dirty